# Java find all timer/subscribed events

Tags: java, actionlistener

I keep track of any timers and subscriptions my App starts, and then check that they are cancelled or destroyed on exit. However, sometimes there appears to be a subscription still running when I next start my App.

Is there a blanket method to find or just cancel subscriptions and timers? Obviously, when I restart my App I no-longer have any pointers to these things.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Pretty weird. Can we had an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)?

Comment: Are you talking about a stand-alone app or webapp?

Comment: @nashuald  My app is loaded into a larger platform that runs on my desktop. The platform remains running, but my individual App can be shut down and restarted.

Comment: Ok. And this timers are started by platform or by your app? If your app start the timers, it is posible that you are not really closing your application, but it stay running on background. To check it try closing your app and check SO task manager and verify wheter jre is still running.

Comment: @nashuald The timers are started by my App. I am running on windows. When I check Process list I see only the main Platform.exe - no additional processes show up